# OnChange for Storing Value of Selected Drop Down Option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have a Material UI dropdown menu. I will make a search later on the basis of the selected option from the drop down menu. How exactly could I use `onChange()` to store the option selected?

For now, I am trying to print the stored value (criteria) using typography at the end but instead of showing the selected value, I get a black page.

```
export default class userSearchPage extends Component<{}, { searchItem: string, criteria: string }>{

  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchItem: '',
      criteria: '',
    };
    this.handleDropDownChange = this.handleDropDownChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleDropDownChange(selected: any) {
    this.setState({
        criteria: selected
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
        <div className='main-content'>
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <DropDownMenu onChange = {this.handleDropDownChange}>
              <MenuItem style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Search By" />
              <MenuItem value={1} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="First Name" />
              <MenuItem value={2} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Last Name" />
              <MenuItem value={3} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Phone Number" />
              <MenuItem value={4} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }} primaryText="Email" />
            </DropDownMenu>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
          <Typography>{this.state.criteria}</Typography>
          <br></br><br></br>
          <SearchBar
            onChange={e => this.setState({ searchItem: e })}
            value = {this.state.searchItem}
            onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
            style={{
              margin: '0 auto',
              maxWidth: 800
            }}
          />
           <Typography>{this.state.criteria}</Typography>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How could I fix this?

***Note: This is typescript***

Added

```
export default class userSearchPage extends Component<{}, { searchItem: string, criteria: any}>{

  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchItem: '',
      criteria: null, 
    };
    this.handleDropDownChange = this.handleDropDownChange.bind(this);
  }


  handleDropDownChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      criteria: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
        <div className='main-content'>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Search By</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.criteria}
            onChange={this.handleDropDownChange}
            displayEmpty
          >
            <MenuItem disabled value="  ">
              <em>Search By</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={1}>First Name</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={2}>Last Name</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={3}>Phone Number</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={4}>Email</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really getting why this question is upvoted as its quite simple and the answer is: keep track of selected options within your state

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Hi, I know about onChange in general but I am stuck with how to use it here. Could you please see my edited question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the DropDownMenu component is just a Material-UI Select component (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#select), you need to update the state of your searchItem to the value of the selected MenuItem.

```
<DropDownMenu onChange={event => {this.setState({searchItem: event.target.value})}>
```

Note, currently in your example the first name and last name item are using the same value of 1.

**Update** - added the comment that contained the solution's code:

Here's an example using Material-UI's Select component instead of DropDownMenu: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hugle-tlfri

Comment: This gives me an error that ```Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS2339```

Comment: Hmm.. an onChange should have access to the event unless your DropDownMenu does not support it.  I do not see a DropDownMenu component in Material-UI API docs. Can you show me the code for the DropDownMenu component or the link to the docs for it? What version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: Here's an example using Material-UI's Select component instead of DropDownMenu: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hugle-tlfri

Comment: Hi, this works! There's just one problem. When nothing is selected, my display only shows an arrow and no text (Search By). Unlike yours, my Search By text is only visible when I click on the arrow. Could you see my updated code and what I am missing?

Comment: At first glance it's because the MenuItem value you have set for the Search By text has a space in it. Leave it an empty quotation.
`<MenuItem disabled value="">`

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. I added the space as an attempt to fix it but no use

Comment: Is criteria in your state set as an empty string or null? In my example I have criteria set as an empty string.

Comment: I tried with empty string too but it's still the same

Comment: I just copied your code into the codesandbox. Did you notice the error in console?
 ```Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.```
This means you need to use empty string for the criteria in state. Also you have to use empty string for the MenuItem value. Doing those two things works just like my example. Double check your console for any other errors/warnings.
The codesandbox now has your code copied with my edits and it works.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownMenu menu should have the 'onChange' event that receives selected option as argument, which you can store in the components state

Comment: Hi, I know about onChange in general but I am stuck with how to use it here. Could you please see my edited question?

Comment: I don't know the exact API of the MaterialUI, but it should be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/fesu9nht/

Comment: Hi, I am using your suggested method. It compiles without an error but gives me a blank page when I select an option. Could you see the updated code in my qs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onChange event to do something when the user is selecting an option. If you want information, you could look at this article: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Hi, I know about onChange in general but I am stuck with how to use it here. Could you please see my edited question?